# How to create a hyperlink which redirects people to a premade page on google when clicked otherwise it won't... (tkinter, python)

Tags: python, tkinter, hyperlink

How to create hyperlink to a premade page in **tkinter** *python* module.

Comment: please elaborate. Where do you want the link in Text WIdget? what have you tried so far? If you have tried what error do you get?  Also, paste a sample code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webrowser is a 2 liner so you should use it.

```
import webbrowser as wb
wb.open("https://google.com")
```

Or use os.startfile()

```
import os
os.startfile("www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample of what I think You want to do:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
import os


root = Tk()

link = Label(root, text='link', fg='blue', font='comicsans 20 underline')
link.pack()

link.bind('<Button-1>', lambda e: os.startfile('www.google.com'))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `webbrowser`.

Comment: @CoolCloud I don't know. probably not the first time I hear about it but I certainly have forgotten about it (haven't had the need to open websites or just the os.startfile stuck with me better) then, till now, so thanks for the reminder, also is there a difference?

Comment: Well `webbrowser` is a module designed for handling such requests I guess, more options.